# MySQL: Consultar año de un campo "Date"

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, select

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos que tiene los siguientes campos:

```
create table Empleado(
    nombre varchar(50) primary key ,
    sueldo integer,
    cod varchar(10),
    fecha_ingreso date,
);
```

**En este caso el nombre es Primary Key debido al enunciado en el que estoy trabajando**. tengo que conseguir mostrar únicamente los registros cuyo año de fecha de ingreso sea 2014 en adelante, si tengo los siguientes registros:

```
insert into Empleado(nombre,sueldo,cod,fecha_ingreso) values("Juan",1600,"P2","2016/7/05");
insert into Empleado(nombre,sueldo,cod,fecha_ingreso) values("Kevin",3200,"T4","2012/01/13");
insert into Empleado(nombre,sueldo,cod,fecha_ingreso) values("Gonzales",4680,"G7","2008/10/24");
```

Debería obtener únicamente el primer registros de cuya año de ingreso es 2016.
Ya que estamos hablando de un campo Date, no tengo muy claro como identificar con un **select** a los empleados con fecha de ingreso mayor a 2014. ¿ Cómo podría encararlo?

Comment: Te faltó mostrar la consulta

Comment: No termino de entender, queres obtener el primer empleado  que ingresó en 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indicas que solo deseas mostrar los que son mayores a 2014 (un año en particular), entonces lo que podrías hacer es apoyarte de una funcion de fecha `YEAR()` y solamente usar un comparador ">" o "<".

```
select * from Empleado where YEAR(fecha_ingreso) > 2011;
```

Otro dato. En tu codigo donde creaste la tabla, hay un pequeño error y se te está escapando una coma.

Answer (score 2):

un modo en el que puedes hacerlo es con la siguiente consulta:
`SELECT * FROM Empleado WHERE fecha_ingreso BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND CURDATE();`
te recomiendo revises la documentacion sobre el manejo de fechas, espero haberte ayudado

Comment: tienes razon, una disculpa en este caso seria CURDATE(), gracias por tu observacion;

Comment: Esta respuesta es mejor que usar `YEAR()` si el rendimiento importa y la columna `fecha_ingreso` formase parte de un índice, porque se usarían los índices, reduciendo así el número de filas que leería la consulta para filtrar los datos, cosa que no ocurre con `YEAR()`, donde los índices no entran en funcionamiento, leyendo **todas las filas** de la tabla para luego filtrarlos, ralentizando la consulta en consecuencia.